# Docker run own iso file as os

Tags: iso-image, docker

Hey all I am trying to run an ISO file as os inside docker for that I have created my iso as tar.gz but I am unable to find a suitable answer to import that file inside docker container.

If anyone can help me in this regard that would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do something Docker wasn't designed to do. Like, for example, replace actual virtual machine with Docker container. What issue are you attempting to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you got an ISO file which content you would like to use as a root file system inside a docker container, then docker does not support directly. You need to convert the ISO image into a docker image first.

A possible workaround is to mount the ISO image using a loop device on host and then call `docker run` with a minimal container using -v to bind top-level directories from the iso into the conatiner.

I.e. something like:

```
mkdir /tmp/iso-mount
mount -o loop,ro path-to-image-file.iso /tmp/iso-mount
top_dir_mounts=()
for i in bin etc lib usr var
do
    top_dir_mounts+=(-v "/tmp/iso-mount/$i:/$i")
done
docker run --rm --read-only "${top_dir_mounts[@]}" --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run busybox
```

That overrides in the container the content of busybox image with files from your ISO file. That could be much simpler if `docker run` allowed to use -v to overrdie the root in the container so all -v above can be replaced with just `-v "/tmp/iso-mount:/"`, but docker rejects that.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I am also new to docker.

1. First of all, extract the ISO to a folder called `ISO` in a docker. (For a windows image it should take 3 mins)
2. You need a dockerfile called `Dockerfile`:

   ```
   ####################
   # Docker ISO Start #
   ####################
   COPY ISO/ /
   ####################
   #  Docker ISO End  #
   ####################
   ```
3. Now execute your docker.
4. It should boot to a image.